# How can I convert a scatterplot into a hexagonal/honeycomb chart?

Tags: math, data-visualization, data-science

I have data in a scatterplot that places colors respective of their lightness (x-axis) and saturation (y-axis):

[image: colors sorted in a scatterplot]

Here's the data set in a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qaMN_JhQ17Eel92TbjRCp6lM36QuCFI1yM-9GqlxzN0/edit?usp=sharing).

I would like to transform this into a hexagonal/honeycomb chart. I did this by hand...finding some "lines" in the data for the edges, and then filling in the middle based on intuition:

[image: colors sorted in a honeycomb chart]

I'm not sure if that's the "best" honeycomb representation of the data, but something that looks okay to me.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could make this process into an algorithm? I have a feeling there's some math or algorithms that would fit this problem which I am unaware of.

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't providing code nor sample data? In Python's matplotlib you'd encounter [`hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/hexbin_demo.html). [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html), check out `C=` and `reduce_C_function`

Comment: @JohanC I added a spreadsheet link into my question which contains the data set.

Comment: @JohanC I don't have sample code since I did this process by hand. I don't really mind whatever programming language you might have a suggestion for me to use.

Thanks for the suggestion about matplotlib's hexbin, but that seems to be a way to visualize point density in a scatterplot (binning). I'm not looking to bin...I'm looking to collapse the two-dimensional scatterplot into a graph where the points are directly next to each other.